# Image button in relative layout android not showing the image

Tags: android, user-interface, android-relativelayout

I am unable to see the image of the Image button when the image is in relative layout. If i use a different layout, image is working fine.
My layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plus"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Image to show the layout and image button]

the same image if i set in some other layout things work fine. Can any one give me some pointers where to look out.
There are no error or warnings in the log.
The actual png image is as follows:
[image: plus.png]

Comment: Do you want to implement floating button?

Comment: Yes was experimenting floating button.

Comment: You can use frame layout.

Comment: @Surender Kumar: can u point me to some resource please.

Comment: Check this one for frame layout example  - http://sampleprogramz.com/android/framelayout.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to implement floating button, the better way will be using existing library:

Add this line on your build.gradle dependencises:

```
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
```

And change your layout to:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

     <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.AddFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/common_ring_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

if you want to customise your floating button for example change colour, add this line as `RelativeLayout` attribute :

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and add the attribute below to the `AddFloatingActionButton` xml

```
fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/floating_button_bg"
fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/floating_button_bg_pressed"
```

Comment: I was looking more like why this was not working for me rather than just getting along with some thing that works.
I was not actually implementing this layout in any app, as said i was just experimenting so want to learn why things are not working.

Comment: It looks like the plus drawable is only white circle - without plus

Comment: Anyway i heard from many in stackoverflow and out refraining people from using third party libraries, as a novice i don't know why. what do you think about that? i just want to know what is good and why it is

Comment: no plus is a png image i can add that image to the actual question. I will do that in a sec thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I used many open source libraries in my live and it always was good for me. If some library has great opinion and make your work easier you should use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72033/discussion-between-konrad-krakowiak-and-thebestshoot).